# What's the correct way to pass the form name from a Private Sub to a Public Sub in another module?

Tags: vb.net

Hopefully a simple question; I have a WinForms application, and have programmed a few low key animations that I have stored in a Module. I'd like to call the module from the Private Sub event, but I'm unsure how to pass the form variable name correctly.

I've tried the VBA way of doing this, by passing the form as an object into the module. This compiles (with Option Strict Off) but then doesn't compile on build:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Call lblFade(Me)
End Sub
```

```
Module frmAnimations
    Public Sub lblFade(frm as Object)
        frm.lblUsername.Visible = False
        frm.lblPassword.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Module
```

I have also tried referencing the module call as `Call frmAnimations.lblFade(Me)` with the exact same issues as above. I've also tried setting the variable as `Form` or `ByRef Form` but this doesn't work either.

Coming from VBA, I expect that this has something to do with the class not being passed in the correct way, and expect it to have something to do with the `sender` and `e` arguments, but I'm a little stuck.

Comment: 1) Use Option Strict On. 2) Instead of `frm as Object`, use `frm as actualNameOfTheForm` so that it can tell that `lblUsername` is an element of `frm`. Or do you want to pass different forms to it?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton - you're absolutely right, various different forms will access this Sub (it should actually be a function really) and pass the reference to it so it can access the same labelled control on each different form. So if the form that I'm passing from is called `myLoginForm` the Public Sub string becomes `Public Sub lblFade (frm as myLoginForm)`?

Comment: In that case, you would need `frm as Form` and then the code will have to find the control: [VS 2010 VB Find Control on Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102137/1115360) should give you an idea of how to progress.

Comment: I'm really sorry - I don't follow that part. I tried referencing it like so `Public Sub lblFade (frm as Form)` but that fails when I get to the `frm.lblUsername.Visible = False` line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why send the entire Class?

Comment: If multiple form has the same controls, you should group them in their own user control. Then that method could be part of that class instead of being shared.

Comment: Because you're telling it that it is a generic Form, it can't know at compile-time that there will be control `lblUsername` on that form, so you have to find the control at run-time.

Comment: How do you mean @the_lotus?